# pass variable inside class extends

Tags: php, tcpdf

My question is about di class "TCPDF"
i cant pass a dinamic backgroud name in class MYPDF extends TCPDF

```
$newimg = 'mypic.jpg'

    class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

        public function Header() {
            $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
            $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
            $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

        $img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'test.jpg';
            $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
            $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
            $this->setPageMark();

        }
    }
```

I would use `$newimg` in

```
$img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.$newimg;
```

I tried to declare global inside

```
public function Header()
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a property in your class and optionally - add getter/setter to it:

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    protected $pic_img = 'someDefaultFile.jpg';

    public function Header() {
        $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
        $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);

        $img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES . $this->pic_img;
        $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
        $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
        $this->setPageMark();

    }

    public setPicImg($value)
    {
        $this->pic_img = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public getPicImg($value)
    {
        return $this->pic_img;
    }
}

// sample usage
$obj = (new MYPDF())->setPicImg($newimg);
$obj->header(); // or other methods
```

Comment: thx u_mulder
my variable is external to  "class MYPDF extends TCPDF {"
how can i pass that?

really thanx